# Stream Analytics query to exclude records

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am successfully joining a reference data stream like this:

```
TenantInput AS
(
SELECT 
    Input.userId,
    Input.tenantId,
FROM
    Input
JOIN 
    Tenants TNTS ON Input.tenantId = TNTS.tenantId
)
```

Whereas TNTS is a JSON file in a storage blob:

```
[
  {
    "tenantId": "t1"
  },
  {
    "tenantId": "t2"
  }
]
```

This works well and the output only contains records for t1 + t2.

On a second output, I would like to have all data except for tenant t1 + t2 and so far I have not found a solution. I tried things like below, but this is not supported.

```
OtherTenantInput AS
(
SELECT 
    Input.userId,
    Input.tenantId,
FROM
    Input
WHERE
    Input.tenanId NOT IN (SELECT * FROM TNTS)
)
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
TenantInput AS
(
SELECT 
    Input.userId,
    Input.tenantId,
FROM
    Input
LEFT JOIN 
    Tenants TNTS ON Input.tenantId = TNTS.tenantId
WHERE TNTS.tenantId IS NULL
)
```

This will only output events from Input, where there is no `tenantId` can be found in TNTS.

Comment: Thanks, must have overlooked this one, easy and straightforward.